# Aggregation and average value with interval in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, average

I have a table with a data-set like this

| Time_1 | Temperature |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-11-20 12:05:15.520 | 75 |
| 2020-11-20 12:06:50.297 | 111 |
| 2020-11-20 12:08:10.513 | 147 |
| 2020-11-20 12:11:10.593 | 72 |
| 2020-11-20 12:10:46.000 | 62 |
| 2020-11-20 12:15:15.263 | 171 |
| 2020-11-20 12:16:34.577 | 238 |
| 2020-11-20 12:16:45.577 | 284 |
| 2020-11-20 12:18:08.373 | 304 |
| 2020-11-20 12:20:57.030 | 299 |
| 2020-11-20 12:22:21.670 | 313 |
| 2020-11-20 12:34:43.733 | 100 |

I want to average the above temperature data based on the time intervals (in most cases are 10min intervals) of another timestamp(time_2) and have something like this

| Time_2 | Records_in_interval | Av_Temp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-11-20 12:05:19.000 | 6 | 106.33 |
| 2020-11-20 12:15:19.000 | 5 | 287.6 |
| 2020-11-20 12:25:19.000 | 1 | 100 |

A problem that I am facing is that the intervals are not always 10 minutes.
This is what i have done so far but its not working.

```
DECLARE @StartDate nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @EndDate nvarchar(20)
     
    SET @StartDate ='2020-11-20 12:00:00'
    SET @EndDate =  '2020-11-20 23:59:59'

SELECT  
      [Date1]= CONVERT(datetime, t2.[time_2], 20),
      DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE,  t2.[time_2], t1.[time_1]) / 10 * 10,t2.[time_2]) AS [date_truncated],
      COUNT(*) AS [records_in_interval],
      AVG(t1.[temperature]) AS [Av_Temp] 

FROM fix.dbo.main_db2 t2
    LEFT JOIN fix1.dbo.main_db1 t1 on DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t2.[time_2], t1.[time_1]) / 10 * 10,t2.[time_2])=t2.[time_2]
    
    WHERE 
     CONVERT(datetime, t2.[time_2], 20)  BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, @StartDate , 20) AND CONVERT(datetime, @EndDate , 20)
    
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t2.[time_2], t1.[time_1]) / 10 * 10, t2.[time_2]),
    t2.[time_2]
ORDER BY 
[date_truncated]
```

Comment: Are these two different tables?  It is unclear what you are really asking.

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: What logic do you use to generate the value '2020-11-20 12:05:19.000' in your first row? It does not exist in your table. In addition, the phrase "in most cases 10min intervals" seems to be more than a bit too flexible as a basis for writing code. Can you expand on that intent?

Comment: you are correct i didn't explained properly. Yes those are two different tables.

Comment: @SMor Time_2 increases on 10 min intervals but in rare cases it might increase in longer or shorter intervals. Each interval in time_2 represents an averaged  measurement over that period of time. So what i am trying to do is for each time interval of time_2 see what measurements on the first table exist and averaged them. For example between 12:05:19 and 12:15:19 there are 5 temperature measurements .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a second table with times, then you can use `join` and aggregation:

```
select t2.time_2, count(temperature), avg(temperature)
from (select t2.*, lead(time_2) over (order by time_2) as next_time_2
      from table2 t2
     ) t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t1.time_1 >= t2.time_2 and
        t1.time_1 < t2.next_time_2
group by t2.time_2;
```

EDIT:

I *think* you can use a correlated subquery for this:

```
select t2.time_2, count(temperature), avg(temperature)
from (select t2.*,
             (select min(tt2.time_2)
              from table2 tt2
              where tt2.time_2 > t2.time_2
             ) as next_time_2
      from table2 t2
     ) t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t1.time_1 >= t2.time_2 and
        t1.time_1 < t2.next_time_2
group by t2.time_2;
```

But to be honest, I don't remember any more what the limitations are in SQL Server 2000.  It is totally archaic at this point.

Comment: Is there any alternative to 'lead' function? as i have compatibility issues with the database i am using. Thanks

Comment: @theo13 . . . `lead()` is supported in *all* supported versions of SQL Server.  The question is then:  Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?  And if so, what version are you really using?

Comment: The database I am getting my data from has a compatibility level SQL server 2000 (80) and from what I found searching you need to have a compatibility level 110 to use the lead function. Correct me if I am wrong as I am new to sql.

Comment: @theo13 . . . I just wouldn't bother trying to do this in SQL Server 2000.

Comment: good to know, any other suggestions/approach would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

if you only have the first table, you could use union to get all three results.

```
SELECT '2020-11-20 12:05:19.000' AS Time_2,
COUNT(*) AS Records_in_Interval,
AVG(temp) AS Avg_Temp
FROM #temp
WHERE time > '2020-11-20 12:05:19.000' AND time < '2020-11-20 12:15:19.000'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2020-11-20 12:15:19.000' AS Time_2,
COUNT(*) AS Records_in_Interval,
AVG(temp) AS Avg_Temp
FROM #temp
WHERE time > '2020-11-20 12:15:19.000' AND time < '2020-11-20 12:25:19.000'
UNION ALL 
SELECT '2020-11-20 12:25:19.000' AS Time_2,
COUNT(*) AS Records_in_Interval,
AVG(temp) AS Avg_Temp
FROM #temp
WHERE time > '2020-11-20 12:25:19.000'
```

Thanks